# Modifying HTTP response headers in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, httpresponse

How can I modify HTTP response headers and remove "Link" and "X-Pingback" in WordPress 4.4.2?

In .htaccess only or in functions.php too?

Not confuse with head area in document please!

Answer (score 4):

```
/* Remove X-Pingback in the HTTP header */

add_filter('wp_headers', function($headers) {

unset($headers['X-Pingback']);

return $headers;

});
```

and this (solution of AITpro) works for me too to remove the link to Rest API in the HTTP header:

/* Remove link to Rest API in the HTTP header */

remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'rest_output_link_header', 11, 0 );

Please check the link [ https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-44-remove-json-api-and-x-pingback-from-http-headers][1]

Comment: so sorry for the same please check this                        https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-44-remove-json-api-and-x-pingback-from-http-headers   @jMike

Comment: Do you have a similar 'template_redirect' solution for "X-Pingback" Header? The wp_headers filter works only on home page for me.

Comment: OK - The solution for WordPress >= 4.4.0 is: All posts and pages must have a ping_status = "closed" in database! --> unset( $headers['X-Pingback']) has no effect!!!

Answer (score 1):

For Wordpress 4.9.1.
In functions.php of your theme:

```
//remove Link header for rest api
remove_action('template_redirect', 'rest_output_link_header', 11, 0 );
//remove Link header for shortlink
remove_action('template_redirect', 'wp_shortlink_header', 11, 0 );
//remove X-Pingback header
add_filter('pings_open', '__return_false');
// Optional. Disable xmlrpc
add_filter('xmlrpc_enabled', '__return_false');
```

More filters and actions in `/wp-includes/default-filters.php`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `functions.php` file:

```
function remove_unwanted_headers($headers) {
    unset($headers['X-Pingback']);
    unset($headers['Link']);
    return $headers;
}

add_filter('wp_headers', 'remove_unwanted_headers');
```

Comment: This solution works only on the homepage - not on other sites. I use genesis framework.

Comment: Do you use caching? This filter won’t allow you to modify headers if your site serves cached pages via a plugin or third-party caching system. The cached page will be served before your wp_headers are filtered.

Comment: I use Browser Caching only in .htaccess. But I turned caching off in my Browser. See my solution in comment of other answer!

Answer (score 0):

This post is old but in my case, I didn't solve using `remove_action` function in the theme's functions.php...I still was seeing the Link header in my Rest Api responses so the way I solved the problem was using the php function [header_remove](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php) in the callback function of my Rest Api

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
        register_rest_route( 'api/v1', '/endpoint', array(
            'methods'  => 'GET',
            'callback' => array( $this, 'get_endpoint' ),
            'args' => array(),
        ) );} );
```

And then in the callback function

```
public function get_endpoint( WP_REST_Request $data = null ) {
header_remove("Link");
//Rest of the code
}
```